# On Wifi/Mobile data Open i want to run a service and Wifi/Mobile data closed i want to stop the service in android

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

### Here is my service class,that i want to start on wifi / mobile data open.

---

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "service starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

---

### Here is my BroadcastReceiver class that is detecting the status of wifi/mobile data open / closed..

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        String status = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatusString(context);
        Toast.makeText(context, status, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
        String statusa = null;
        if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
            statusa = "Wifi enabled";
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    BackgroundService.class.getName());
            context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
            statusa = "Mobile data enabled";
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                    BackgroundService.class.getName());
            context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));
        } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
            statusa = "Not connected to Internet";
        }

    }
```

}

### Here is Another class that is associated with Recever class

```
public class NetworkUtil {

public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI;

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    }
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
```

}

## I have mentioned service and BroadcastReceiver in AndroidManifest.xml file and also mention uses-permission..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
   if (info != null) {
       if (info.isConnected()) {
           //start service
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
           context.startService(intent);
       }
       else {
           //stop service
           Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
           context.stopService(intent);
       }
   }
```

Comment: What is the issue for Android 6 ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking connectivity, you can use JobScheduler for this which has methods present inside it to handle these situations, the benefits would be your app would also become compatible for the latest android version. Below is the code you can add to configure your job service.

```
public void scheduleDummyJob() {
        ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(this, DummyService.class);
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceComponent);
        builder.setMinimumLatency(1 * 1000); // wait at least
        builder.setOverrideDeadline(3 * 1000); // maximum delay
        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED); // require unmetered network
        builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(true); // device should be idle
        builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // we don't care if the device is charging or not
        JobScheduler jobScheduler = getSystemService(JobScheduler.class);
        jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
    }
```